# Random Double Issues

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble generating a random double number. I have to create a function that takes no arguments and returns a double (between 0 and 100), the random number. Expect every time I try to create it, it returns a value of 1.

I also have to use a few symbolic constants.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

double randDouble();

const double UPPER_BOUND = 100.0;
const double LOWER_BOUND = 0.0;
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;

double randDouble()
{
    int randomInt;
    double randomDouble;

    srand(time(NULL));
    randomInt = rand() % 100 + 1; 
    randomDouble = LOWER_BOUND + (randomInt / RAND_MAX / ( UPPER_BOUND  - LOWER_BOUND));

    return randomDouble;
}

int main()
{
    cout << randDouble();
    return 0;
}
```

Another thing is, I have to use a pre-given formula for it.

`lower bound + ( random integer / (maximum possible random number / (upper bound - lower bound))`

Comment: The randomInt you put into your "formula" is in the range 1 ... 100. Then you should use these values in your formula and not RAND_MAX! Or even better: forget your randomInt and put your call of rand into the formula. Also: I wouldn't call srand each time, but only once at the beginning for your program.

Comment: `randomDouble = LOWER_BOUND + ( rand() % 100 + 1 / (UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND));`  So something like this? I still get 1 as a return.

Comment: No, 
LOWER_BOUND + ((double)rand() * (UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND)) / RAND_MAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not calling `randDouble` in your `main`, but try to print the function itself. This will always print `1` or `true`, depending on whether `boolalpha` is set. Your compiler would have warned you about that if you had enabled a more aggressive warning level. This is generally recommended.

When you fix this, you will notice that you always get zero. This is because `randomInt / RAND_MAX` is always zero because of truncating integer division.

When you fix that, you will notice that the returned values are not as desired because your formula is incorrect.

A lot of such problems can be avoided by using the modern [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) which already does all the hard work for you.

Comment: I don't think I'm able to use `std::`, this is a small part of an  assignment. And we haven't discussed that yet.

Comment: @VictorAmaro You already are using `std::cout`. Actually, the missing `std::` is why your code does not even compile for me. Then, `std::uniform_real_distribution` is part of the current C++ standard, just as much as `int`, `std::cout` and `std::rand`, all of which you use. If you have special requirements, please state them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a better and a cleaner way:

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    std::random_device rand_dev;
    std::mt19937 gen(rand_dev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 100);

    // demo.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        // call dist(gen) whenever you need a random variable.        
        cout << dist(gen) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code uses C++11 and won't work on earlier versions.

Comment: Okay, so, this is only a small part of an assignment. And we haven't even discussed `std::` yet. And I have to do it in a function, to be able to call it in other functions.

Comment: Check this [link] http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm to know what std is.
you can define the first three lines in main() globally and then use dist(gen) in whatever function you need.